# cout doesn't print anything sometimes in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm programming in C++ with Netbeans 8.2 at school, these computers have Ubuntu 14.04 and `gcc-4.3`.

The cout randomly works altought it doesn't send any errors in the log.

Every computer here has the same problem.

main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Posible (and expected) output:

```
Hello World!

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0,; real time: 0ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Other posible output:

```
RUN FINISHED; exit value 0,; real time: 0ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Comment: Where are you using `cin`?

Comment: Unrelated, but gcc 4.3 is... ancient. Consider getting your school to update.

Comment: " altought it doesn't send any errors in the log." what log? usually if something goes wrong during runtime you dont get a nice error message

Comment: While I was redacting this, I realized that the cin was not the problem, I forgot to remove the cin from the question. The problem is with the cout itself.

Comment: Run your program outside of your IDE and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't, you're observing a problem with NetBeans.

Comment: The same code works fine compiling and running it from a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this going to `Project Properties -> Run -> Console Type -> Standard output`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the compiler prints out and finish without being noticed. So you can use cin to check if that is happening to you.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    int test;
    cin >> test;
    return 0;
}
```

Here the compiler will wait for you to enter a value, so you will have plenty of time to see your output.

Comment: RUN FINISHED; exit value 0,; real time: 0ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms  being displayed does indicate that output window is present/open and is not exiting after program execution.